Fetch principal values from External Credential without callout
Is there a way to access principal's authentication details from ExternalCredential in apex.
I tried:
ConnectApi.ExternalCredential ec = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getExternalCredential('GCP_Key');
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(ec.principals));

But it outputs:

22:16:07.258 (403496362)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|[ {
"authenticationStatus" : "Unknown",
"id" : "0puIg0000004CAVIA2",
"parameters" : [ ],
"principalAccess" : [ ],
"principalName" : "GCPprivateKey",
"principalType" : "NamedPrincipal",
"sequenceNumber" : 1
} ]

Whereas, in principal I do have Parameters.
I also tried:
ConnectApi.ExternalCredential ec = ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getExternalCredential('GCP_Key');
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(ec.parameters));

But no luck.
Is there a way to access parameter values?


We are trying to build a decryption logic in salesforce. Where the public key id will be passed along with the encrypted text - sounds like a XY problem, What are you trying to achieve?

I updated the issue.

Principal parameters' values are injected by the platform at runtime, you can't read their values in Apex. You can do some crypto via a formula in NC/EC. It's unclear what outcome (the X in XY) you're after. For encrypting something on a per-party basis, a symmetric-key algorithm such as AES will achieve the same outcome as asymmetric and save yourself much of this effort. But encryption without message authentication is weak and not acceptable in real world crypto, symmetric or asymmetric.

For a symmetric-key flow, salesforce needs to have a private key stored. I was looking for a place to store this private key. As custom setting and custom metadata is not an option here, because of security reasons. I am checking if we can use external credetntial to store privateKey and public key Id, and the access that in apex.

Are you rolling your own crypto? The Crypto class only supports a symmetric algorithm (and only AES at that) for decrypt/encrypt, One implementation of message auth (EtM) is described in the doc.

Not our own crypto, we will use Apex Crypto class, with this method public static Blob decrypt(String algorithmName, Blob privateKey, Blob initializationVector, Blob cipherText) where private key will be stored in salesforce. This Private key will be same private key used to encrypt the data in the external system, and IV will be passed to us by external system. But to store this private key securely, I am trying to find a secure place in SF.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.secure_coding_guide.meta/secure_coding_guide/secure_coding_storing_sensitive_data.htm is still current. Daniel Ballinger's answer in this Q&A reiterates the safest path of using a managed package for this chunk of code.
